# Calling yield in callback, redux saga gives me an exception why?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, redux-saga

so I commented out where it gives me a traceback.

```
export function* watchFileReader(){
const action = yield take("DROP_FILE")
console.log('action', action)
let file = action.file[0];
readFile(file, function(e){
  sessionStorage.removeItem('img')
  console.log('alskdjfalsdjkf', e.target.result)
  sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)
  // yield put({type: "UDATE", {img: e.target.result})
   })
}
```

update: 
this is my promisified function to get the code to work.

```
 function readFileWithPromise(file){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   readFile(file, function(e){
     if (e){
      resolve(e)
     }else{
      reject(e)
     }
   })
 })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't use yield in callback , there are two ways to avoid this:

1. **cps** effect . [DOCS LINK](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#cpsfn-args)

   ```
   import { cps , ...  } from 'redux-saga/effects';

   export function* watchFileReader(){
     const action = yield take("DROP_FILE")
     let file = action.file[0];

     let e = yield cps(readFile,file); <----------------

     sessionStorage.removeItem('img')
     sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)
     yield put({type: "UPDATE", img: e.target.result})
   }
   ```

   note :  function must call cb(null, result) to notify the middleware of a successful result. If fn encounters some error, then it must call cb(error) in order to notify the middleware that an error has occurred.

   ---
2. ***promisify*** **your function**

   ```
   function readFileWithPromise(file){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            readFile(file,(err, res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res));
       });
   }
   ```

   and then call it

   ```
   import { call, ...  } from 'redux-saga/effects';

   export function* watchFileReader(){
     const action = yield take("DROP_FILE")
     let file = action.file[0];

     let e = yield call(readFileWithPromise,file); <----------------

     sessionStorage.removeItem('img')
     sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)
     yield put({type: "UPDATE", img: e.target.result})
   }
   ```

**[LIVE DEMO for two examples](http://www.webpackbin.com/E1r-D5yib)**

Comment: I cannot wait to try once i get in front of my computer.

Comment: thanks I got it to work using promisify. you are awesome!